# Installing Java Runtime with Saltstack

Tags: java, centos, redhat, salt-stack

I'm using Salt to configure a bunch of Centos machines (rpm-based) and I need to install the Java runtime.  I've seen some discussion of doing this with Ubuntu-based machines but I wonder if anybody has done it on Redhat-based distros.  The problem is getting past the "accept license" dialog without user intervention.

Answer (score 1):

You can actually pre-seed the answers to those interactive questions.  Here's a thread from the salt-users mailing list showing how:  https://groups.google.com/d/msg/salt-users/95Q707FFWYo/CdcJN7FPpRAJ

Comment: You can't pre-seed rpm.

Comment: Good call, I missed that in the original post.  Is this something we just need to support in salt, or does RPM just not support it?  Are we dead in the water here?

Comment: Oracle is intentionally a PITA regarding its license to use java.  You can't even download it from them without hacking up a cookie or using  a web browser.  Search for "how to download oracle java using wget"

Answer (score 0):

There is this nice [saltstack-formula/sun-java-formula](https://github.com/saltstack-formulas/sun-java-formula)

> Formula to set up and configure Java JREs and JDKs from a tarball archive sourced via URL.

It can be installed using [formulas documentation](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/development/conventions/formulas.html). I did not test this on a centos installation, but it uses tarball installation so maybe it would work. If someone tests it on a rvm based system, please comment here! ;)

I successfuly installed this on a debian machine with the following pillar:

```
java_home: /usr/lib/java
java:
  source_url: http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u79-b15/jre-7u79-linux-x64.tar.gz
  jce_url: http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jce/7/UnlimitedJCEPolicyJDK7.zip
  version_name: jdk1.7.0_79
  prefix: /usr/share/java
  dl_opts: -b oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie -L
```

It installed java-jdk successfully, but it failed to install jce. I created [issue #20](https://github.com/saltstack-formulas/sun-java-formula/issues/20) for this just in case, but I don't actually need jce (at least, not now).